# package.json not able to locate file

Tags: npm, package, ng-packagr

I have added a script in my script section of package.json which is present at root directory

```
"packagr": "ng-packagr -p src/ng-package.json"
```

But while running this script using

```
npm run pacakgr
```

gives error saying "no such file or directory" and tries to find my file at location

```
root/ng-package.json
```

instead of

```
root/src/ng-package.json
```

Does we need some configuration to map files?

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake and it happened because I wrote the command in microsoft word.
When you type - in word and press space-bar it converts that character to something else.

Accidentally I used "–" character instead of "-"

Though python interpreter shows same ascii value for both the characters.